# Sorting is not working on IP address column in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, sorting, ng-grid

I have an grid view which has 4 columns like below:

```
IP           | Name | Status  |Value

192.168.1.3  |MAS   | UP     |x 

192.168.1.5  |HGR   | UP     |Y 

192.168.1.10 |UYR   |DOWN   |Z

192.168.1.7  |IOR   |UP      |P
```

I am using ng-grid framework to display these. Here sorting is not working on ip address column , its working fine for other columns .
My column definition is as below :-

```
columnDefs : [{
                    field : 'ip',
                    displayName : 'IP',
                    width : '25%'
                }, 
                {
                    field : 'name',
                    displayName : 'NAME',
                    width : '25%'
                },
                {
                    field : 'status',
                    displayName : 'Status',
                    width : '25%'
                },
                {
                    field : 'value',
                    displayName : 'Value',
                    width : '25%'
                }];
```

Any idea on that?

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: No , its not giving any error .. though data are displaying for all the columns , only the thing is that sorting not working on ip address column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the column should do string sorting. In case, you mean, it should do number sorting rather string sorting, you can try using a custom sort function for the ip column,

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    field: 'ip',
    displayName: 'IP',
    width: '25%',
    sortFn: function (a, b) {
      if (a == b) return 0;
      if ( +a.replace(/\./g, '') < +b.replace(/\./g, '')) return - 1;
      return 1;
    }
  },
  {
    field: 'name',
    displayName: 'NAME',
    width: '25%'
  },
  {
    field: 'status',
    displayName: 'Status',
    width: '25%'
  },
  {
    field: 'value',
    displayName: 'Value',
    width: '25%'
  }
];
```

hope this helps

Comment: still its not working. I used your code as well . Its able to sort on other columns , but not on ip . Is it a CSS problem ? just i am guessing .

Comment: have you used `sortInfo` in the `gridOptions` object?

Comment: I have used sortInfo like this :-                                                              sortInfo: { fields: ['ip'], directions: ['asc']}, 
but when i am refreshing browser then once its coming in sorting order , but later its not sorting.

Comment: Hey shakib , its working now.. thanks ... i used  
sortFn: function (a, b) {
      if (a == b) return 0;
      if ( +a.replace(/\./g, '') < +b.replace(/\./g, '')) return - 1;
      return 1;
    }
Thanks a lot...